# Power function by means of recursion

Tags: c, recursion, math, exponent

The implementation should compute a number to the nth power using recursion, however, every call to itself, keeps "nb" unchanged, while power decrements. I've tried using a accumulator variable but this reinitializes to default with every repeated call. Is there a way to save nb * nb to nb, without adding an extra parameter? or losing the base value?

When I run ft_recursive_power(3, 10); in a c visualizer (ctutor) and pass it these arguments, it displays that nb remains 3 throughout the execution, and returns 177147, while it should accumulate the multiplication and return 59049. Or am I missing something?

```
int   ft_recursive_power(int nb, int power)
{
  // 0 to the 0th case
  if (power == 0 && nb == 0)
    return (1);
  // recursive case
  if (power > 0)
    return (nb * ft_recursive_power(nb, power - 1));
  return (nb);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to "save nb*nb to nb"? it appears that the code works fine by itself.

Comment: The last line should be `return 1;`, but it is otherwise fine.

Comment: "*[E]very call to itself, keeps "nb" unchanged, while power decrements*" -- why yes, it does, and that's a perfectly valid way to do it.  It's cleaner than what you seem to have in mind, in fact.  The successive multiplications are performed on the return side.

Comment: I am not sure you fully understand recursion or the behaviors of local variables (including arguments) in a function. When this function recurses, each instance of `nb` in each call is separate from the others. The first instance of the function in the call chain is not going to lose the value of its `nb` if another instance changes its `nb`. And, with a function this simple, there is no reason to keep any sort of accumulator. Each function can merely use a simple expression to calculate the value it needs to return: `nb * ft_recursive_power(nb, power-1)` in the general case.

Comment: So, given that you have a simple expression that works, why would you want to add more code that changes `nb`? As dbush noted, the only error is in what the function returns for a base case: When power` is zero (and `nb` is not), the code falls through to `return (nb);`. But nb\*\*0 is 1, not nb, so the function ought to return 1 in this case. Fix that, and the routine works.

Comment: Incidentally, `return` is a statement, not a function, and it does not need parentheses. You can `return 1;` instead of `return (1);`, and so on.

Comment: I don't get your "however". n^k = n * n^(k-1), with n^0 = 1, is one way to specify the power function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an incorrect result because your base case is wrong.

The value 177147 is 3<sup>11</sup> as opposed to 3<sup>10</sup>, which means you're multiplying one extra time.  That happens because you `return nb` in the base case when `power` is 0.

When raising a number to the 0 power the result is 1, so your base case should be 1.

```
int   ft_recursive_power(int nb, int power)
{
  // 0 to the 0th case
  if (power == 0 && nb == 0)
    return 1;
  // recursive case
  if (power > 0)
    return nb * ft_recursive_power(nb, power - 1);
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here your problem:

```
if (power == 0 && nb == 0)
```

should be replaced by

```
if (power == 0)
```

and added case (nb == 0) as well

if (nb == 0)

The function should work for negative power as well, so I suggested change the return type to float.

It is my solution:

```
float   ft_recursive_power(int nb, int power)
{
    // 0 to the 0th case
    if (power == 0)
        return 1;
    if (nb == 0)
        return 0;

    // recursive case
    // power is positive
    if (power > 0)
        return (nb * ft_recursive_power(nb, power - 1));

    // mean power is negative
    else
        return (ft_recursive_power(nb, power + 1) / nb);
}
```

Comment: Removing the `return (nb);` statement causes undefined behaviour if `power < 0` since it falls off the end.

Comment: @Peter yeah, should we care if power is  negative? in that case return (nb) is not correct as well

Comment: This returns 1 for `ft_recursive_power(0, 1)`, but 0\*\*1 is 0. The `(power == 0 && nb == 0)` you said should be changed was handling the special case 0\*\*0, and it was correct for that, although it can be handled more gracefully. It is incorrect to state that it was the problem.

Comment: It seems the OP does not properly understand recursion, lifetimes of automatic objects, or the fact there may be multiple instances of them. Merely giving an answer with code that may work without explaining the **concepts** is not a good answer.

Comment: @Loc Tran - given that `power` is of type `int`, it can be negative.   Since there is no way to prevent the caller from passing a negative value, it is better to handle that case in some way other than introducing undefined behaviour.   It would be better to call `exit()` (which has behaviour that is well specified, even if it won't please a user) than, as you have, to specifically introduce undefined behaviour which could practically do anything - including corrupt the host system, poison data used by the program, reformat a hard drive, etc etc.

Comment: @Peter for negative case, I think should change return type for float. I edited in my answer

Comment: *I think should change return type for float.* Doing something like that changes the function from one that provides an **exact** answer (for a limited input) to one that provides an appoximate answer.